# How to use GitLab / Github pages with a monorepo?

Tags: angular, github, deployment, gitlab, continuous-integration

Is there a way to use Github / Gitlab pages with a monorepo?
I have 1 Gitlab repo that have 3 projects:

- Angular app - admin.
- Angular app - users.
- Backend.

I will be using a paid Heroku dyno to deploy the backend. I could use (indeed, I was using) heroku too deploy the dist folders of the two Frontend projects. But because we modularized a lot our apps, and the free Heroku dynos are not specially fast, I was wondering if Github / Gitlab pages were faster.
I used Gitlab pages once, but for 1 project with Gitlab CI. Does anyone knows if it is possible to do something like a page per branch, or something that I could use to deploy my 2 Frontend apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not really. Each project has exactly 1 pages site. Each deployment must contain *all* the assets for the entire site; you cannot independently build/deploy multiple apps to a single pages site.

Though, you *can* have multiple projects each with their own pages site. You can keep the monorepo setup and just use the additional projects as a way to deploy more sites. You can use [multi-project pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html) to send artifacts built in the monorepo pipeline to downstream projects pipelines with their own pages deploy jobs.

Comment: It seems exactly what I need. Thanks! ( Cant vote you answer because of low rep  ):